# Why doesn't asynchronous processing work on the first run?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous, transactions, event-listener

Server Info: java 17, spring-boot 3.1.4

Since the parent server (WCS) only wants to know if it received the data it gave it, the logic of converting the data into a form suitable for use by the subsidiary, storing it in a table, and then passing it on is time consuming, so we've separated it out.
This way, we can actually respond to the parent server in about a second instead of 8 seconds.
I kept the implementation as simple as I could remember, but when I tested it, I ran into the following issue.

When debugging inside the isolated @TransactionalEventListener, the first time I saved to "localhost:8080/save/1", I got a 200 response after debugging.
On the second request, the 200 response arrived first, even though I stopped debugging inside the properly isolated @TransactionalEventListener.

Why on earth is the first request waiting for the logic in the @TransactionalEventListener to finish?

Since this is a test case, we temporarily used @GetMapping.

```java
import com.example.demo.biz.OrderBizService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WcsWaveController {

    private final OrderBizService orderBizService;

    @GetMapping("/save/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity save(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        orderBizService.save(id);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderBizService {

    private final WCSWaveService wcsWaveService;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Long id) {
        System.out.println("OrderBizService Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        WCSWaveEntity wcsWaveEntity = new WCSWaveEntity();
        wcsWaveEntity.setId(id);
        wcsWaveEntity.setName(Long.toString(id));
        wcsWaveService.save(wcsWaveEntity);

        PickingSaveEvent pickingSaveEvent = new PickingSaveEvent();
        pickingSaveEvent.setWcsWaveId(wcsWaveEntity.getId());
        pickingSaveEvent.setName("test1");
        publisher.publishEvent(pickingSaveEvent);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PickingWaveService {

    private final PickingWaveRepository pickingWaveRepository;

    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Async
    public void save(PickingSaveEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TransactionalEventListener Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        PickingWaveEntity pickingWaveEntity = new PickingWaveEntity();
        pickingWaveEntity.setId(1L);
        pickingWaveEntity.setWcsWaveId(event.getWcsWaveId());
        pickingWaveEntity.setName(event.getName());
        pickingWaveRepository.save(pickingWaveEntity);
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
@Getter @Setter
public class PickingSaveEvent {

    private Long id;
    private Long WcsWaveId;
    private String name;
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncThreadConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("test");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

The first attempt doesn't give an immediate response and isn't what you expect
[First Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGDRj.png)

After the second attempt, the response comes right back asynchronously, as expected.
[following requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZmD0.png)

Comment: Debugging and trying to explaining threading is generally a bad idea. Depending on how the debugger acts, it can stop all executing threads.

Comment: Thank you @M. Deinum!!
So, is there anything in my code that would be problematic about the threads I've separated to give faster responses? I'm still a junior developer and want to learn!!!

Comment: @M. Deinum
Oh I'll have to test it by changing it to Thread.sleep or something, not debugging, and post back! Thanks

Comment: @M. Deinum Oh my!! I did it with Thread.sleep() instead of debugging and it works fine thank you bless you!

Comment: You can configure the debugger in Intellij to halt only the current thread and not the whole JVM.